# Xprinter USB for React-Native

Tags: react-native, tspl

I use a printer xprinter xp-350b connected using USB. How do I code a React-Native app?

Are there any lib that support TSPL commands and USB printer connections?

I want to my app(React-Native) can connect xprinter by usb and printer label.